Texture paint imperfection / discoloration. See image
What causes these imperfections when texture painting on a low poly UV mapped object ?
They appear randomly elsewhere on the object than where I am painting.
See image. The arrow is pointing at what I mean


How about a photo of your whole screen and including the UV map so we can see how the map coincides with the artifacts? From this picture all I can tell is that something that looks like triangular faces is showing up in your field of red - that could be stray faces in your UV mapping overlapped by other islands or something else.

You can try increasing the "Bleed" value of the brush, play also increasing the "Margin" value of UV islands.

